# How program for graceful removal/or no removal if device node is in use

Tags: linux-kernel, char, driver, linux-device-driver, pci-e

I have this device node created using mknod command for a pcie driver.

```
/dev/pciedrv
```

Upon removing the driver while device node file is open (in use), the system crashes.

```
rmmod -f pciedrv
```

Is there a way to do a graceful exit? Also how to handle the case when user application accessing the file terminates unexpectedly  before closing the device node.

Comment: Please ask Questions if not clear

Comment: Make a shell script that checks if the device node is in use (with `lsof`) before running `rmmod` ?

Comment: can we do it in driver code?

Comment: I think so. But in this case it doesn't use lsof since the driver can already know if it's in use by another program.

Comment: can you help me where can I do this in code. BDW I checked, below command doesn't list pciedrv node, even when it is in use.
    lsof |grep pciedrv

Comment: This question is unclear. First, did you create that driver yourself (do you have the source of it) ? Second, what are you trying to do ? If you just want a way to remove the kernel module without crashing then my shell script solution is the easiest (use lsof to find programs using the device node, kill them/wait for them to exit before rmmod'ing the kernel module).

Comment: Yes I have source of it. file node is */dev/pciedrv*
**For first sol using script**
I run this command and i get no result (Is this right way?)
*lsof |grep pciedrv*
*Where should code to check this go in second case, I mean in driver src without script making rmmod intelligent enough to handle this*

Comment: I got the first solution and successfully implemented. I am killing the process before rmmod.

Comment: So unless you know C and want to spend an hour implementing a graceful exit in the module itself, just stick to the shell script solution and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

The `rmmod` help says:

> -f, --force
>   forces a module unload and may crash your machine.

Don't use `-f`.
A correctly written driver will then block module removal as long as it is still in use.

A graceful exit requires that the application that has opened the device node exits gracefully.
But even if the application terminates unexpectedly, the kernel will close the file.

Comment: So what's the difference at the level of callbacks in the driver when you call rmmod with and without -f ? Does system call remove callback for each device if you don't give it -f?